# How to fix the array state filtering data in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [itemsClicked, setItemsClicked] = useState([]);
  const dataList = [
    { id: 1, name: "jake" },
    { id: 12, name: "edd" },
    { id: 13, name: "john" }
  ];

  const highlight = (data) => {
    setItemsClicked((array) => {
      let itemClicked = array.includes(data)
        ? array.filter((x, i) => x.id !== data.id)
        : [...array, data]; // What I'm trying to do here is to add a new field which is 'active' >> [...array, {...data, active: true}];

      return itemClicked;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {dataList.map((item, i) => (
        <div
          style={{
            borderColor: itemsClicked[i]?.active ? "1px solid green" : ""
          }}
        >
          <button onClick={() => highlight(dataList[i])}>HIGHLIGHT</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What I'm trying to do here is to create a toggle which is to highlight the `div`.
but my problem is on the state instead of it will remove the data object, it will continue appending. how to fix it?

for example when I try to click the first data which is `jake`, the output should be like this in `itemsClicke`

```
[{ id: 1, name: jake, active: true }]
```

but when I try to click again it will just remove it from the list, but on my side, it continuing to append the data which is wrong

```
[{ id: 1, name: jake, active: true },{ id: 1, name: jake, active: true },{ id: 1, name: jake, active: true },{ id: 1, name: jake, active: true }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove the `itemsClicked` state and put the `dataList` in a state variable to have control over it:

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([
  { id: 1, name: "jake" },
  { id: 12, name: "edd" },
  { id: 13, name: "john" }
]);
```

Now, you need to check an `isActive` property to conditionally add some styles, so you need `isActive` but it's not in the current `dataList` and you created `itemsClicked` to solve this issue. But there are some simpler solutions like adding a property on the fly with your `dataList`.

You can implement `toggleHighlight` function to change `isActive` property:

```
const toggleHighlight = (id) => {
  setDataList((prevState) =>
    prevState.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, isActive: !item.isActive } : item
    )
  );
};
```

this `toggleHandler` will accept an id and take a for loop over the `dataList`, it finds the clicked item. if it's an active item so it changes it to false and vice versa.

let's recap and put all things together:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "jake" },
    { id: 12, name: "edd" },
    { id: 13, name: "john" }
  ]);

  const toggleHighlight = (id) => {
    setDataList((prevState) =>
      prevState.map((item) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, isActive: !item.isActive } : item
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {dataList.map((item) => (
        <div
          key={item.id}
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            paddingTop: 10,
            border: item.isActive ? "2px solid green" : ""
          }}
        >
          <p style={{ padding: 5 }}>{item.name}</p>
          <button onClick={() => toggleHighlight(item.id)}>HIGHLIGHT</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Try this on a live playground
[image: Edit add unique key for each child]

Answer (score 0):

```
array.includes(data)
```

won't return true because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50371323/17357155

Answer (score 0):

Just use this. It's a simple example. I used itemsClicked only for storing the ids

```
const highlight = (data) => { 
      if(itemsClicked.indexOf(data.id) == -1)
      {
        setItemsClicked(prevData => { 
          return [...prevData, data.id]
        })
      }  
    }

 {
  dataList.map((item, i) => (
    <div
      style={{
        border:
          itemsClicked.indexOf(item.id) > -1 ? '1px solid green' : '',
      }}
    >
      {itemsClicked.indexOf(item.id) > -1 ? '1px solid green' : ''}
      <button onClick={() => highlight(dataList[i])}>HIGHLIGHT</button>
    </div>
  ))
  }
```